# Bounding a video into a box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a video fit into a div with a given width and height. The problem is that if the video is higher than the height of the div, the video exceeds the limits of this div. I'm wondering if there is a CSS rule or something to cut the video to the limits the div.

Here is the problem:
[Video out of the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2vAQ.png)

The code is simple:

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
    <video id="timelapse" src="videos/Timelapse_campamento.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#timelapse {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -3;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video to fit to the div, you can add `height: 100%` to the video (css), and if you want it to be cut, you can add `overflow: hidden` to the div.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be

Add height:100%; in CSS

```
#timelapse{
width: 100%;
height:100%;
/*changed in here*/

z-index: -3;
position: absolute;
}
```

And if you want it to stretch video or fit the video inside the box
you can use
object-fit: fill;

```
#timelapse{
width: 100%;
height:100%;
object-fit: fill;
z-index: -3;
position: absolute;
}
```

Can also use `overflow: hidden;` to not display the part that has been overflowed